# No module named '__future__' error when trying to spin my motor

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Trying to spin my motor I got an error in Thonny:

> `No module named '__future__'`

When reinstalling Python and MicroPython nothing changes. I used pip to install future and `__future__`, but `__future__` wasn't valid and future is already good. When looking up solutions they either won't work or are confusing me.

My code:

```
from gpiozero import Motor
from time import sleep

fan = Motor(14,15)

fan.forward()
sleep(5)
fan.stop()
```

Comment: plz provide more information `__future__` is dunder method not module.
what's __gpiozero__ ?